# BIP39 security: 24 words vs. 12 words + 12 word passphrase

Tags: mnemonic-seed

Does using a 12 word BIP39 mnemonic phrase in combination with another 12 word BIP39 mnemonic phrase used as an additional passphrase provide the same security as a 24 word mnemonic phrase without passphrase?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes it’s the same since there are 2048^24 mnemonic + passphrase combinations in both cases.

Slightly longer answer: Technically the second case is a bit better because the 12 words in the mnemonic have a checksum so they only contain 128 bits of entropy vs 132 bits in the 12 words in the passphrase. Any 12 words is a valid passphrase but any 12 words are not a valid mnemonic.

Comment: Yes you can put anything in the passphrase but my understanding of OPs question is he wants to use the same wordlist to pick 12 words for a passphrase

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I explicitly asked for "another 12 word seed used as an additional passphrase". The question was about a comparison of the security of a 24 word seed without passphrase vs. a 12 word seed with another 12 word seed used as passphrase.

Comment: @wieland.gmeiner Thanks for the clarification. My comment was motivated to help authors clarify their contributions, I misunderstood your question so I'll edit it for you to make it clearer for anyone in future who has the same question and is searching for answers.